# How to translate "(optional)" on Symfony2 form

Tags: symfony

I have some form types which are not required. The form labels should be localized, and that is easy.

But when you configure a certain form type as `'required'=>'false'`, a word "(optional)" appears just after the type label.

What would be the right way to translate "optional", or to disable it?

Btw. I don't see any way at all now.

Thank you

```
 "require": {
     "php": ">=5.3.3",
     "symfony/symfony": "v2.3.0",
     "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
     "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
     "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
     "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
     "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
     "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
     "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
     "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
     "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
     "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*@dev",
     "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*@dev",
     "twitter/bootstrap" : "dev-master",
     "cg/kint-bundle": "dev-master",
     "raveren/kint": "dev-master",
     "mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
     "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master",
     "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "2.*"
},
```

Comment: which version of symfony2 are you using? please provide your composer.json ! this rendering of **optional** string after the label is - as far as i know - not standard behavior so it might be rendered by some bundle you're using.

Comment: I added dependencies list from composer.json. Symfony version is 2.3.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "optional" string rendering is being introduced by the **mopa/bootstrap-bundle**.

It can be found in the bundle's [**Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig**](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig#L328).

The "optional" string is added in the block **form_label_asterisk**:

```
{% block label_asterisk %}
    {% if required %}
        {% if render_required_asterisk %}
             <span>*</span>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        {% if render_optional_text %}
            <span>{{ "(optional)"|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</span>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock label_asterisk %}
```

As you can see the rendering requires you to set a translation_domain for the optional string to be translated. The correct implementation would have been using a fallback to 'messages'

```
...
<span>{{ "(optional)"|trans({}, translation_domain|default('messages')) }}</span>
...
```

### Solution:

Remove the optional rendering completely by adding to your config.yml:

```
# app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    mopa_bootstrap.form.render_optional_text: false
```

... or add `render_optional_text => false` to your form options.

The BootstrapBundle's overriding of the default form-type can be found [here](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/blob/master/Form/Extension/LegendFormTypeExtension.php#L35).

Alternatively you can remove the optional string by overriding the block in a single form

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block label_asterisk %}
    {% if required %}
        {% if render_required_asterisk %}
             <span>*</span>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock label_asterisk %}
```

More information about overriding form elements can be found in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16749394/1832745).

Comment: Certainly, I thought I'm supposed to vote it up. Figured where to click now :)

Answer (score 0):

See [Allow translation of (optional) #277](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/pull/277) issue on bundle's repository. This code has changed a lot since the accepted answer of this question.

It's now using `translation_domain` like this:

```
{%- if render_optional_text %}&nbsp;<span>{{ "(optional)"|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</span>{% endif %}
```

I was personally using `JMSTranslationBundle` so to extract this, I made a quick dumb class like this:

```
<?php
namespace ACME\Bundle\ACMEBundle\Tools;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator;

class TranlsationsOverrides {
    /**
     * @param Translator $translator
     */
    function __construct(Translator $translator) {
        $this->translator = $translator;
        /**
         * @see vendor/mopa/bootstrap-bundle/Mopa/Bundle/BootstrapBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig:653
         * https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/pull/277
         */
        /** @desc("(optional)") */
        $translator->trans('(optional)');
    }
}
```

So when running `php app/console translation:extract my_local`, it gets extracted and can be translated :)